# seaborn boxplot sort appearance of boxes

Tags: seaborn, boxplot, pandas-groupby

Here is my code:

```
order = sorted(subway_df.conds.unique())
g0 = sns.boxplot(subway_df.ENTRIESn_hourly, groupby = subway_df.conds,  data=subway_df, palette = "Set2", order = order )
g0.set(yscale = 'symlog')
g0.set_xlabel('conds', fontdict={'fontsize' : 14})
g0.set_ylabel('ENTRIESn_hourly', fontdict={'fontsize' : 14})
fig.suptitle('Hourly entries at various weather conditions', fontdict={'fontsize' : 16})
```

and the following graph:

[image]

I would like to find a way to sort the appearance of boxes by mean or variance as opposed to alphabetical order. Thanks!

Comment: Change how you're defining `order`.

Comment: yes, I figured that out but I seem to entangle in code at this point. I can sort the means for example by: grouped = subway_df.groupby(subway_df['conds']) and later with: asorted(grouped['ENTRIESn_hourly'].mean()) which gives me a nicely ordered table. Now what I want is to retrieve the location of means and corresponding weather condition.

Comment: I'm not sure what `asorted` is but you can use the index of the series returned by the groupby.

Comment: solved by one line of code and lots of bits from SO: 
`order=subway_df.ENTRIESn_hourly.groupby(subway_df.conds).median().sort_values().index.values` 
Now it can be sorted by whatever property alike.

Comment: https://github.com/suszka/sns.boxplot/blob/master/sns_boxplot_sort.ipynb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rank plot in seaborn boxplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39214484/how-to-rank-plot-in-seaborn-boxplot)