# python reader graph gives a blank canvass

Tags: python, seaborn

`Mtcars` is a public dataset in R. I'm not sure it's a public dataset in python.

```
mtcars <- mtcars
```

I created this boxplot in R and part of what I'm doing is reordering the y-axis with the `reorder()` function.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = reorder(origin, mpg), color = origin)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(title = "Mtcars", subtitle = "Box Plot") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  ylab("country")
```

[image]

Now in python I have this boxplot that I created with seaborn:

```
plt.close()

seaborn.boxplot(x="mpg", y="origin", data=mtcars)
plt.suptitle("Mtcars", x=0.125, y=0.97, ha='left', fontweight = 'bold')
plt.title("boxplot", loc = 'left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I'm trying to render it now but the same kind of treatment for R doesn't work.

```
plt.close()

seaborn.boxplot(x="mpg", y=reorder("origin", 'mpg'), data=mtcars)
plt.suptitle("Mtcars", x=0.125, y=0.97, ha='left', fontweight = 'bold')
plt.title("boxplot", loc = 'left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

It's not surprising it doesn't work because it's a different language; I do know that! But how would I do this reordering in python using Seaborn? I'm having trouble understanding if this is even part of the plotting process.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39214484/7758804

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute a custom order and feed it to seaborn's boxplot `order` parameter:

```
import seaborn as sns

mtcars = sns.load_dataset('mpg')

order = mtcars.groupby('origin')['mpg'].median().sort_values(ascending=False)

sns.boxplot(x="mpg", y="origin", data=mtcars, order=order.index)

plt.suptitle("Mtcars", x=0.125, y=0.97, ha='left', fontweight = 'bold')
plt.title("boxplot", loc = 'left')
plt.show()
```

*NB. `order` also acts like a filter, so if values are missing, of non-existent they will be omitted in the graph*

output:

[image: custom order]

Comment: Your answer is also pointing out that my original boxplot was sorted by the mean, which is apparently a default in R and maybe median in this case is the better option

Comment: @hachiko here you can use any function you want (mean, median, min, max, std…)